# Apply cohen.d to multiple columns

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a data frame of survey question responses. I would like to estimate Cohen's d effect sizes for each response using `cohen.d` from `effsize`.

Here are the first 6 rows of my data frame:

```
structure(list(id = c("HO1001", "HO1001", "HO1002", "HO1002", 
"HO1003", "HO1003"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), grit.distract = c(1, 
1, 3, 2, 1, 2), grit.setback = c(5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4), grit.obsess = c(3, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 2), grit.work = c(4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5), grit.goal = c(2, 
3, 2, 1, 4, 4), grit.focus = c(3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3), grit.finish = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 3), grit.diligent = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4), grit.mean = c(3.25, 
3.25, 2.875, 2.625, 3.5, 3.375)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I successfully converted the `df` into wide format to use `effsize` on the summary statistics i.e. mean/total as follows:

```
structure(list(id = c("HO1001", "HO1002", "HO1003", "HO1004", 
"HO1005", "HO1006"), pre = c(3.25, 2.875, 3.5, 2.25, NA, NA), 
    post = c(3.25, 2.625, 3.375, 2.5, 2.75, 2.875), change = c(0, 
    -0.25, -0.125, 0.25, NA, NA), highconf = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L)

cohen.d(grit.tot$pre, grit.tot$post, na.rm = T)
```

What I would like to do  is calculate the effect sizes for each survey item i.e. grit distract, grit.setback, etc. between time 0 and time 1 (please no comments on my statistical methods). Given that I have plenty more data frames like this and don't want to do them all individually, I believe that I should use a `function` and a loop such as `apply` but I'm not sure how to construct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question this may help.
If your data frame from the first part of your questions is stored as `dt` running the following should give the cohen d for each survey item.

```
lapply(dt[c(-1,-2)],function(x) cohen.d(x ~ dt$time))
```

`dt[c(-1,-2)]` removes the ID column and the time column as you don't want to run the cohen d test on these.